# Why does first call to a database using entity framework takes longer even though this database has been called before?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ms-access

I am using entity framework to get data from my Access database. I have found this scenario where I call the database using three different queries. And it doesn't matter how I organize them, the first one always takes 2 to 3 seconds and the rest of call executes in fraction of Milliseconds. Here's a small example:

```
var myData1 = await myRepo.GetData1();
var myData2 = await myRepo.GetData2();
var myData3 = await myRepo.GetData3();
```

In this case `myRepo.GetData1()` takes 2-3 seconds. And rest of the code runs super fast. If I re-arrange them and call `myRepo.GetData2()` first then this one will take 2-3 seconds and `myRepo.GetData1()` will run super fast.

At first I thought this was the first time this database was accessed, but after debugging I realized this db connection has been opened before.

Is there any configuration I'm missing?

---

EDIT: After debugging further it looks like the connection gets "reset" after couple of seconds. So after this block if I query the the same DB after 2 seconds it again takes 2-3 seconds to return the data! Is there a way to keep the connection "alive"?

Comment: Initialization of the DbContext has a first time cost, especially if you have many tables

Comment: @ErikEJ that was my first guess too. But this db has been accessed before. So doesn't that mean it has already been done?

Comment: Has the DbContext been initialized before?

Comment: @ErikEJ: yes, and I got data from the DB before this.

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework DbContext has a warm up cost the very first time that DbContext definition is referenced in a process. This warm up is to resolve all of the configured mappings and doesn't really have much to do with establishing a DB connection.

When your application first starts up, you can kick off a simple, fast query to initiate that warm up such as:

```
var result = _context.Users.Any();
```

This can serve as the warm up plus a verification that the database connection is available. The initialization is static so newly scoped DbContexts (Such as per-session or scoped in `using` blocks) won't incur additional warm up costs.  If you have multiple DbContexts defined (I.e. bounded DbContexts, then each definition needs to be warmed up even if pointed at the same database.

Comment: IMHO add that query to an `IHostedService`, the http pipeline wont process requests until all hosted services have started.

Comment: That's the part that confuses me. I HAVE queried the database before this point. From debugging further it looks like the connection gets "reset" after couple of seconds. So after this block if I query the the same DB after 2 seconds it again takes 2-3 seconds to return the data!

Is there a way to keep the connection "alive"?

Comment: Is this an MS Access database as per your tags? It may be some behaviour or config needed with that provider, or some other detail in your particular implementation. (Are you using EDMXs, or EntityTypeConfiguration, etc.?) With providers like those for SQL Server or PostreSQL there is just a 1-time spin-up cost when using the first instance of a DbContext. If you're seeing that hit more than once for the same DbContext then that would hint at possibly something else.

Comment: When DbContexts are disposed the connections are typically released. This is normal, usually desired behaviour. One option might be to employ a manual connection handler via something like a DbContextFactory or the like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-management Potentially MS Access and EF connection management is more expensive than other providers? (I would look to eliminate other possible culprits in the code/config before going manual)